# WPF UI Automation With Infragistics Controls

Tags: wpf, testing, infragistics

Does anyone have any good pointers/examples/links for writing WPF UI automation tests with applications utilising Infragistics controls?

Comment: I'd imagine (hope) that the Infragistics forums would be more helpful for this kind of question. That said, it's not clear from your question why automation of Infragistics WPF controls would be any different from automating standard WPF controls. Then again, it is Infragistics so they've probably done something completely against the grain.

Comment: +1 @Kent Boogaart. Link http://community.infragistics.com/forums/t/32221.aspx On request they would provide a sample through support.

Comment: +1 @Avator Infragistics provided sample on request which I hadn't thought to do...should have been the first thing I did

Answer (score 0):

**CodedUI**, that comes with **Visual Studio Premium/Ultimate editions,** seems to work fine with most of the controls

Answer (score 0):

I have used UI Automation and TestStack.White with Infragistics. The White framework is built on top of MS UI Automation famework so you get best of both worlds.
Example links are:

- [WPF ItemsControl with TestStack White](http://abusanad.net/2016/12/19/wpf-itemscontrol-with-teststack-white/)
- [teststackwhite](http://teststackwhite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [UI Automation Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx)